# jQuery toggle custom animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, toggle

How can I make a custom animation?

```
$('button').toggle(function() {
  anim.go("fadeOut slow", $("mydiv"));
}, function() {
  anim.go("fadeIn slow", $("mydiv"));
});
```

Toggle is working, but first appears toggle animation, then mine. How can I disable default toggle anim? Like `toggle(0)` P.S I've tried to add `0` to my code, but then second function isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: Your issue is because in the modern versions of jQuery `toggle()` no longer works in the manner you've used. You'll need to use `click()` and then check the visibility state of the element and then run the required animation

Comment: Thank you so much, please write answer. `if($("mydiv").is(":visible")) {` works perfectly!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I added it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because in the modern versions of jQuery `toggle()` no longer works in the manner you've used, ie. two separate functions called alternately.

Instead you'll need to use `click()`, check the visibility state of the element and then run the required animation based on that, eg:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var $div = $('#mydiv');
  var action = $div.is(':visible') ? 'fadeOut' : 'fadeIn';
  anim.go(action + " slow", $div);
});
```